# how to access login details from all components in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, session, authentication, react-router, react-context

I have a login component which checks login credentials and makes the user login to the application. after login, the user is redirected to a component named as exchange.there are other components which uses the login credentials(username and password), other than the exchange component to make axios get requests. How do I make the username and password available to all the other components? I have used links in the buttons to redirect the user to different routes. In different routes, different components are rendered. I want to use login details to be available in all these components.

Comment: You mean to say, you want to create session variables?

Comment: can you please explain how this can be done through session variables?

Comment: You can use redux, and fetch the store value from any components

Comment: can you please give me an example @KajolChaudhary

Comment: You can use React Context for storing data that should be available across components. You can find examples in [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)

Comment: how can I do this with react context @BoyWithSilverWings?

Answer (score 2):

If we talk in react terms, if many components want to access some data or if one component updates some data which has to be available to other components which are or aren't into the DOM at the moment, it's always best approach to use a redux store which stores your data and connect your components to it so that they will have access to the store data the moment they are added to the DOM.

So dispatch an action when the user enters the login and password to update the store state and then read them in all the components you want.

Here is for starters.
https://redux.js.org/

Comment: here some have said this could be done with session variables, using react context and using redux.what is the best way to do this?

Comment: I would say, use redux. Validate the login credentials and if it's correct, save them in redux store. This way your components which are connected to the redux store will always have access to the data. This is why redux store is also termed as one source of truth. You can google this term for better clarity.